# MongoDB Journals not been persisted using Docker-Compose & Windows 10 Home

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm using windows 10 home with docker toolbox

The only shared folder in the vbox settings that been set by default:

[image]
while using the following yaml:

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9000:8081
```

Changed the permitions of the folder that everyone has a full control
Getting the following error in mongodb logs:

```
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.192+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1587720630:192587][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1587720630:192587][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.193+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (26) [1587720630:193681][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_fs_rename, 241: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy Raw: [1587720630:193681][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_fs_rename, 241: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.204+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1587720630:204261][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1587720630:204261][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.205+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (26) [1587720630:205347][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_fs_rename, 241: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy Raw: [1587720630:205347][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_fs_rename, 241: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.218+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1587720630:218021][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1587720630:218021][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.219+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (26) [1587720630:219113][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_fs_rename, 241: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy Raw: [1587720630:219113][1:0x7f12e9fe8b00], connection: __posix_fs_rename, 241: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.221+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.221+0000 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 26: Text file busy
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.221+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 860
mongo_1          | 2020-04-24T09:30:30.221+0000 F  -        [initandlisten]
mongo_1          |
mongo_1          | ***aborting after fassert() failure
mongo_1          |
mongo_1          |
```

Inside the folder I can see the following been created:

[image]

Any idea what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported

> WARNING (Windows & OS X): The default Docker setup on Windows and OS X
>   uses a VirtualBox VM to host the Docker daemon. Unfortunately, the
>   mechanism VirtualBox uses to share folders between the host system and
>   the Docker container is not compatible with the memory mapped files
>   used by MongoDB (see vbox bug, docs.mongodb.org and related
>   jira.mongodb.org bug). This means that it is not possible to run a
>   MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/issues/80#issuecomment-464408049

Workaround - running cron backup

```
docker volume create mongodbdata



services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongo-backup:
    image: istepanov/mongodump:4.2
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/mongodbBackup:/backup
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://user:pass@mongo:27017
      CRON_SCHEDULE: "* * * * *"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```